# Is it possible to set a filter in Google Data Studio with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

Do you have any experience in setting filters in Google Data Studio with GAS?

I created a report in Data Studio that have sensitive information that has to be accessed only by the user who entered that information.

Among my data report columns I have one column that brings the email of the user. I am embedding the report in a Webapp that collect the user email when the page is loaded. I would like to get this email information and set the filter in my Data Studio report that will be displayed in a iframe tag. I am looking for an alternative to set a filter in the main page of my report.

I read the Data Studio service for Apps Script but I still could learn if this is possible!

if you have some experience with this interaction with Data Studio through script I will be glad to know!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Webapps but perhaps you should apply the filter in the original spreadsheet and store in a separate sheet. Then use that sheet to pull to the webapp. This would not be dynamic.